# Printing cookies within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working on a website and I am trying to read cookies from JavaScript and print them onto a paragraph tag `<p>`. I've tried the following code (besides document.print because it does the whole page.)

```
<script>
function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

var u = getCookieValue("username");

document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = u;
</script>

<p id="usr" class="acct"></p>
```

The username cookie is "electroner1998", and I've made sure that the `<p>` tag exists. (Nothing happens to the `<p>` tag. It stays blank.)

Comment: It should be just `u` instead of `u()`

Comment: `u` is a string, why do you try to call a string with `u()` ?

Comment: even w/o it don't work.

Comment: consle.log your return from getCookieValue either the cookie isnt there or something is wrong with your regex

Comment: or your `<p> tag doesn't have an `id="usr"` ... ? Please create a [mcve] ...

Comment: how do i console.log it? `console.log(getCookieValue("username"))`

Comment: Yea your regex is not working, not for me anyway. in your getCookieValue() func console.log(b) and play around will you can get your regex working

Comment: I've also tried the other cookie way before messing with this. The W3Schools cookie reader. `function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I can't read regex, but if the issue lies with it, you could do the following which is easier to read:

```
function getCookieValue(a) {
    var c = document.cookie.split(a + "=")[1];
    if (c.includes(";")) {
        return c.split(";")[0];
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

From your edit, you also need to call a function to set the inside of your `<p>` tag. Just putting

```
var u = getCookieValue("username");
document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = u;
```

... inside a script tag isn't going to make them work; you would need to call them from inside a function on the page, or using `window.onload`:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var u = getCookieValue("username");
        document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = u;
    }

    function getCookieValue(a) {
        var c = document.cookie.split(a + "=")[1];
        if (c.includes(";")) {
            return c.split(";")[0];
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling cookies I like to use a library called [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) which can get, set and remove cookies easily.

```
var u = Cookies.get('username');
```